# What's the most efficient way to scatter plot a pair of 2D lists on top of each other in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Working with python and matplotlib. Lets's say for example I have the following lists:

```
A=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
B=[[4, 2, 6], [3, 2, 1], [5, 1, 4]]
```

Each row of these lists represent a single scatter plot, A being x-axis and B being y-axis. Is there an efficient way of stacking these scatter plots on top of each other into a single scatter plot? I have already tried a "for" loop:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    plt.scatter(A[i], B[i])
```

It works, but it's a bit slow when working with larger numbers of entries. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing multiple calls to scatter? You could flatten the lists and then do one call to `plt.scatter(A,B)`.

Comment: @Chrispresso I didn't think of that. Worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a reason to do multiple calls to scatter, I would recommend flattening the lists and doing a single call to `plt.scatter` like so:

```
import itertools
A=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
B=[[4, 2, 6], [3, 2, 1], [5, 1, 4]]
A_flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(A))
B_flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(B))
plt.scatter(A_flat, B_flat)
```